# Mdadm only able to assemble some of the drives from hardware array

Tags: mdadm, hardware-raid, raid5

After using ddrescue to back up the disks of a failing hardware RAID5 array (from a perc h700 controller) to images, and following [Nikita's answer to my previous question](https://serverfault.com/a/1147888/1060778) to create overlays, I attempted to assemble the array with mdadm: `mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md1 /dev/nbd1 /dev/nbd2 /dev/nbd3 /dev/nbd4 /dev/nbd5`, where `/dev/nbd*` are the overlays of the 5 disks. However, this returned the error `mdadm: superblock on /dev/nbd3 doesn't match others - assembly aborted`.

Running `mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/nbd1 /dev/nbd2` worked, with the response `mdadm: Container /dev/md1 has been assembled with 2 drives (out of 3)`. But trying to add the next drive to the array with `mdadm --add /dev/md1 /dev/nbd3` caused a segfault!

What else should I try, in an effort to recover this array?